# How to typeset certain characters bold by default?

Tags: equations, formatting, bold, characters

I'm currently writing my thesis and have a lot of equations to write down. In order to make those more readable I would like to differentiate vectors and scalars by writing vectors with bold characters. As it is rather tedious to write `\boldsymbol{x}` every time I use the vector `x`, I would like to know if it is somehow possible to make those characters bold by default.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! How would LaTeX make the difference between `x` as a vector, and `x` as a number? Maybe you never ever use x for numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Write `\newcommand{\vx}{\boldsymbol{x}}` in the preamble and use `\vx` whenever you want `x` in bold font. For any other letter of interest, just replace `vx` with `v<you letter>`

Comment: That's usually bad practice. a) Do not use one-character command sequences (especially as there are many that already have a meaning) and b) You should usually check if you're in math or not.

Comment: He says that he uses `\boldsymbol{x}` and want something shorter or automatic. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: Probably `\vx` (for “vector x”) is better.

Comment: egreg is right. But especially you should adjust your advice so that one-character sequences are not the general idea. If you replace x with one of k,c,l,b,d,r,u,v,t,o you'll notice issues (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters)

Comment: In my opinion, it's more the problem of an `editor`: how to have a shortcut to make it type automatically `\boldsymbol{}`, or `\mathbf{}`,  with the cursor between the braces. Most modern editors let you  easily define such a shortcut.

Comment: @egreg. Thanks for the idea. Now the post is modified accordingly